# render an embedded image in an rdlc report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have some content from a WYSIWYG editor that I want to output into an rdlc report in asp.net. I have setup a test and the markup looks correct, except that the image does not display.

Here is an example of the data, which is displayed in a TextBox.

```
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"><br></p><p>arial</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><font face="Arial Black">arial black &nbsp;</font></p><p><font face="Arial Black"><br></font></p>
```

Is there a better control or a setting to do this?

thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

i see you have `base64` of image content. Don't you want to pass a path to your image through report parameters?

Like this:

```
    ReportParameter picPar = new ReportParameter();
    picPar.Name = "Path";
    picPar.Values.Add(@"file:///C:\Pic.png");
    reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(picPar);
```

Here is a [simple tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-and-display-external-Image-in-RDLC-Report-from-code-behind-in-ASPNet.aspx) how you can do it without code. Also you might interested in how you can pass image through `DataSource` in [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/6194/display-image-in-rdlc-report-microsoft-report-viewer.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. the image is already embedded in html from a wysiwyg editor. it could be positioned anywhere in the markup so i dont know how this would work. are you suggesting pointing the source of the img to the parameter or something?